# Como puedo contabilizar Views and unique views en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL

| id | date | ip | usr | device | via_city | via_state | via_country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | 2021-08-05 15:58:04.070 | 201.170.64.206 | 86 | 1 | Tijuana | BC | Mexico |
| 105 | 2021-08-06 10:39:50.747 | 201.170.64.207 | 108 | 2 | Mexicali | BC | Mexico |
| 106 | 2021-08-07 13:40:09.993 | 201.170.64.208 | 86 | 3 | Tecate | BC | Mexico |
| 107 | 2021-08-08 16:49:44.967 | 201.170.64.209 | 108 | 3 | Tijuana | BC | Mexico |
| 108 | 2021-08-09 16:49:44.967 | 201.170.64.206 | 89 | 2 | Tecate | BC | Mexico |

Pero necesito contar las visitas totales y visitas únicas

Hasta ahorita solo puede contar las las visitas totales:

```
;WITH ViewList
        AS 
        (
            SELECT [via_id]
              ,[via_date]
              ,[via_ip]
              ,[usr_id]
              ,[dev_id]
              ,[via_city]
              ,[via_state]
              ,[via_country]
            FROM [usr_views_analytics_via]
            WHERE usr_id = 86 and (via_date >= '2021-07-23 00:00:01' and via_date <= GETDATE())
        )

        SELECT v.[via_city], 
        count(v.[via_id]) as total_views
        FROM ViewList v
        group by via_city
        order by total_views desc;
```

La cual me arroja el siguiente resultado:

| via_city | total_views | uniqueViews |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 98 | 3 |
| Tijuana | 8 | 1 |

como puedo contabilizar las visitas únicas?

La regla es para contabilizar un visita única es cuando:

1. No existe un registro con esa IP
2. Cuando existe la IP pero es de otro dispositivo

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que tu base de datos es MySql y no SqlServer?

Comment: Una disculpa, ya edite la pregunta, si es SQL

Comment: SQL es le lenguaje, te falta agregar el motor de base de datos que estás utilizando.

Comment: No me percate de ello, Listo.

Comment: Ok, no hay problema. Probá la query y avisame cualquier cosa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edité la respuesta para SqlServer, que al parecer es el RDBMS que estás utilizando.

Asumo que la columna `via_date` es de tipo datetime en función de la información de que dispongo. Asumo también que la columna `via_id` no tiene valores repetidos.

Para contar las visitas únicas utilizo la subquery `ViewUnique`, partiendo de la subquery `ViewList` agrupo por `via_ip` y `dev_id` y restrinjo los grupos cuya cantidad sea 1. Según lo especificado la visita es única cuando solo se encuentra un registro con esa IP y un determinado dispositivo (Quizas tu quieres contabilizar las visitas únicas por ciudad, en ese caso tendrías que agregar `via_city` al `GROUP BY`.

Luego en la query principal hago un `LEFT JOIN` entre ambas subqueries (`ViewList` y `ViewUnique`), y agrupando por `via_city` cuento los registros de cada una de ellas.

```
WITH ViewList AS (SELECT via_id, via_date, via_ip, usr_id, dev_id, via_city,
                          via_state, via_country
                  FROM usr_views_analytics_via
                  WHERE usr_id = 86 AND 
                        via_date >= '2021-07-23 00:00:00' AND via_date <= GETDATE()),
                        
     ViewUnique AS (SELECT MIN(via_id) AS via_id
                    FROM ViewList
                    GROUP BY via_ip, dev_id
                    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)                        

SELECT v.via_city, COUNT(v.via_id) AS total_views, COUNT(vu.via_id) AS uniqueViews
FROM ViewList v
LEFT JOIN ViewUnique vu ON v.via_id = vu.via_id
GROUP BY via_city
ORDER BY total_views DESC;
```

Comment: Lo estuve probando y no me funciono. Las Vistas únicas me arrojan un cero en cualquiera de los casos

Comment: [Aquí lo puedes chequear con tus datos de ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=297768dcb5c211dd9f11ada9aebdd440), ambas vistas únicas contabilizan 1.

Comment: Armá un [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) con datos de ejemplo (como hice yo) donde no sea correcto el resultado que retorna mi query y lo revisamos.